# Remove duplicate lines from many LARGE files

Tags: linux, sorting, duplicates

I have many many large files (>100 1-10GB) with the same data format that contain a lot of duplicate lines between them.
Files A B C D could have the same line somewhere in all of them and I only want to remove ALL duplicate lines between ALL files.
Either merging them into 1 and removing duplicates is fine, but I would rather keep them separate and just remove lines that exist somewhere else (if even possible).

I have tried sort -u *.txt > deduped.txt but memory is a MASSIVE problem (idk if it will work because I canceled it as it was taking AGES).
Peaking at max memory and cpu 24/7 with this method.

Comment: That is going to be computationally expensive no matter how you do it. The only thought I have would be to use a string hash function like *OPENSSL_LH_strhash*, or *MURMUR3 murmur3_32 hash* to hash each of the strings and then the sort/unique on the hash should be less expensive than a full string comparison (so long as a majority of the strings are greater than 32 characters).

Comment: It will probably work because `sort` writes data to disk if it runs out of memory. Of course that will slow things down a bit, but it's better than crashing.

Comment: You could sort each file in parallel using something like `ls | xargs -i% -n1 -P 10 sort % -o %` then you could use sort with the merge option `sort -m -u`. I'm not sure this actually gains you total time since I think sort operates in parallel anyway, but if the memory hit is your main concern you could control how many initial sorts take place simultaneously and the merge at the end shouldn't be too bad.